# Three.js OrbitControls panning and scene rotation

Tags: three.js

I need to rotate the environment. And since three.js does not support cube env rotation, I'm going the simplest way and modifying `scene.rotation.y`, as suggested by three.js contributors everywhere.

It all works fine until the camera is panned. Try it for yourself here https://stackblitz.com/edit/threejs-env-rotate and observe the camera wobble when the scene is rotated using the slider.

How do I remedy the wobble? I seem to be unable to find the algorithm that would solve this. I tried rotating the `controls.target`, but maybe my 3D math is off.

Comment: I looked at your demo, but I don't see the camera wobble you're talking about. Did you update the demo after posting it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing happens because `controls.target` is not influenced by `scene.rotation`, so the wobbling happens due to the camera trying to follow the specified target. This means you should also apply the same rotation to `controls.target`.

But this is not sufficient. When you attach the camera straight to the scene under the influence of transformation, the camera's matrix changes, but `position`, `rotation` and `scale` don't. Which makes it so the behavior of OrbitControls further deviates from what's expected.

My suggested solution is for you is to avoid attaching the camera to the scene and, instead, rotate the camera's position and control's target alongside with the scene.

```js
const radians = e.target.value * Math.PI / 180
controls.target.applyAxisAngle( camera.up, radians - scene.rotation.y )
camera.position.applyAxisAngle( camera.up, radians - scene.rotation.y )
scene.rotation.y = radians
```

[Live Example - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k96w7hn/)

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve, and it works like a charm, so I'm going to accept this answer. Thank you.